# Eclipse plugin to give guided tour?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Guided tour libraries are quite common in web-based applications.

A small wizard pops up on first usage, and leads the new user through parts of the user interface.

Has anyone heard of a similar library for Eclipse/RCP?

(I've Google'd but can't find one)

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of such a library for Eclipse RCP but a viable alternative could be achieved by providing a custom welcome menu and dedicated cheat sheets (in an Eclipse-based product).

### 1. Providing a custom welcome dialog

When Eclipse IDE opens for the first time it shows a [Welcome Dialog](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fwelcome.htm). You can enhance it or [provide your own](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_intro.htm&cp=2_0_19_0) that could, for instance, present the different features available and provide quick access to your different wizards.

### 2. Providing dedicated cheat sheets

[Cheat sheets](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_cheatsheet_simple.htm) can be used to provide step-by-step tutorials. A user can access them through the `Help > Cheat Sheets...` menu but you can also link them in the welcome dialog.

Comment: Thanks +Emmanuel (and welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Ironically, it's actually a welcome dialog that we're hoping to replace with the guided tour.

Oh, and for about 10 years we used cheat sheets, only moving to pdf tutorial so that we could integrate images into the content (which we couldn't do with the cheat sheet).

Thanks again,
Ian